# Ruby / Big Decimal - Unable to perform a save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I have a column which needs to hold 18 digits of value. Its defined in my rails file as

Schema.rb

```
 t.decimal  "revenue",    precision: 23, scale: 5
```

Now when I try the following in console:

```
obj = Model.last
obj.revenue = 999999999999999999 ( 18 nines)
obj.save is returning false
```

( I have a validation that the maximum revenue should be less than 1000000000000000000 ( 1 followed by 18 zeros)

Validation on modal:

```
validates :revenue , numericality: {:greater_than => WBConstants::MIN_REVENUE_LIMIT, :less_than => WBConstants::MAX_REVENUE_LIMIT}, allow_blank: true
```

The error message says the value should be less than 100...(1 followed by 18 zeros)

I am unable to save. 
The database I am using is sqlserver
The column data type is decmial(23,5)

Comment: What is the column type in the database?

Comment: Could you show your validation definition?

Comment: You can add underscores to enhance readability: `1_000_000_000_000_000_000`

Comment: How are those constants in validation defined?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Rails. The value is [internally parsed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L64) by `Kernel.Float` and `Kernel.Float(999_999_999_999_999_999)` returns `1.0e+18`.

Comment: @Stefan - Isn't rails using BigDecimal for decimal points? EDIT: Never mind, just read the link you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Rails and there's already a [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17104).

You could [perform custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) until the fix is merged.

#### What's causing this bug?

Rails internally [converts the value](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L64) to a float using `Kernel.Float`:

```
f = Kernel.Float(999_999_999_999_999_999)
#=> 1.0e+18

f < 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
#=> false

f == 1_000_000_000_000_000_000
#=> true
```

#### Why is this happening?

Because floats have limited precision and can only represent some integers exactly:

```
(999999999999999000..1000000000000001000).map { |i| i.to_f.to_i }.uniq
#=> [999999999999998976,
#    999999999999999104,
#    999999999999999232,
#    999999999999999360,
#    999999999999999488,
#    999999999999999616,
#    999999999999999744,
#    999999999999999872,
#   1000000000000000000,
#   1000000000000000128,
#   1000000000000000256,
#   1000000000000000384,
#   1000000000000000512,
#   1000000000000000640,
#   1000000000000000768,
#   1000000000000000896,
#   1000000000000001024]
```

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation to solve this issue until now.
please check link below:
[Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

Hope this help you.

Comment: Yeah, The same solution was suggested above.